# C++ PHP extension

Tags: c++, fstream, php-extension

I wrote a very simple PHP extension. Now I want it to read in a file on startup. Here is my code:

```
#define PHP_COMPILER_ID  "VC6"


#include <fstream>  
#include "php.h"


int number = 0;
ZEND_FUNCTION(use_html);

//declaration
ZEND_MINIT_FUNCTION(use_html);
zend_function_entry use_functions[] = 
{
    ZEND_FE(use_html, NULL)
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};

zend_module_entry use_html_module_entry = 
{
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
    "First_Extension",
    use_functions,
    ZEND_MINIT(use_html), 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
    "1.0.0-tutorial",
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

ZEND_GET_MODULE(use_html);

ZEND_FUNCTION(use_html)
{
     bool useHtml;

     if(zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "|b", &useHtml) == FAILURE)
     {
         E_ERROR;
         return;
     }

     if(useHtml)
     {
         php_printf("This string uses <a href='#'>Html</a>");
     }
     else
     {
         int sum = 0;
         int i = 0;
         for(i;i<100000;i++)
             sum += i;

         RETURN_LONG(number);
     }

     return;
}

ZEND_MINIT_FUNCTION(use_html)
{
    std::ifstream infile("file.txt");
    number++;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

and the error message is:
Error   5   error C2491: 'std::endl' : definition of dllimport function not allowed c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream    1004    1   php_extension1

I also tried to change the order of include, but it didnt help.

***EDIT***

here is the problematical part from ostream

```
_CRTIMP2_PURE inline basic_ostream<char, char_traits<char> >&
    __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL endl(basic_ostream<char, char_traits<char> >& _Ostr)
    {   // insert newline and flush byte stream
    _Ostr.put('\n');
    _Ostr.flush();
    return (_Ostr);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any use of std::endl in your code. Post the part of the code that uses it.

Comment: thats my whole code. the problem occures if i include <fstream>. I guess it includes ostream and there is the problem.

Comment: You mark your compiler as `VC6` but code that you sent to us for `std::endl` is not for `VC6` compiler, can you please report the compiler that your PHP and your program built by it?

Comment: phpinfo() says: PHP 5.3.5 Compiler MSVC6 (Visual C++ 6.0). I use VS 2010. "can you please report the compiler ... your program built by it?" -- i dont get the 2nd part. which program's complier do u ask for? ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution: for php extension developement I only added `#include <string>` in zend_config.w32.h and it compiled fine. for more info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/vcgeneral/thread/94ed21c2-7128-4149-8a8f-05fc195a812c